# Problem with File Upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I recently started using a new server for a client and am having problems with file uploads in PHP.

Everything in the past has worked but now it does not.

```
$path= "wedding_uploads/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['sliderfile']['name'];
if($ufile !=none){
if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['sliderfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
```

Anyone know what's wrong with this?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: No error or warning from log files?

Comment: Try using `move_uploaded_file` instead of `copy`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - also make sure that `enctype='multipart/form-data'` is set on the `<form>`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be picking up the file. The $HTTP_POST_FILES don't have value's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not come across this method of uploading before, I always use `move_uploaded_file()`. And it's not clear what your `$ufile` variable is.

I tend to use something like:

```
$path = "wedding_uploads/".$_FILES['sliderfile']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sliderfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
    // Success
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be picking up the file. The $HTTP_POST_FILES doesn't have value's. <input name="sliderfile" id="sliderfile" type="file" />

Comment: Try using just $_FILES instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$HTTP_POST_FILES` with `$_FILES`